# custom naming of search permalink /search/

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, search, htaccess

I found this snippet online …

```
function search_url_rewrite_rule() {
    if ( is_search() && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
        wp_redirect(home_url("/search/") . urlencode(get_query_var('s')));
        exit();
    }   
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'search_url_rewrite_rule');
```

This transforms my `?/s=term` into `/search/term` which is almost what I want.
I'd like to use the german word "suche" instead of "search" inside my permalinks.

I thought of changing `home_url("/search/")` to simply `home_url("/suche/")` but that doesn't work.

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because you haven't told WordPress how to handle that page. You can do so by applying a rewrite rule in the following manner.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_63716_search_rule' );
function wpse_63716_search_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^suche/([^/]*)?', 'index.php?s=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Don't forget to flush the permalinks after adding the above code.