# Custom permalink for search and pagination

Tags: permalinks, pagination, search, urls, archives

@Chip Bennet helped me out in a previous question and posted his entire pagination function. This function works perfectly fine for me but I'd like to have custom permalinks in german.

```
/**
 * Paginate Archive Index Page Links
 */
function oenology_get_paginate_archive_page_links( $type = 'plain', $endsize = 1, $midsize = 1 ) {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;  
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

    // Sanitize input argument values
    if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'plain', 'list', 'array' ) ) ) $type = 'plain';
    $endsize = (int) $endsize;
    $midsize = (int) $midsize;

    // Setup argument array for paginate_links()
    $pagination = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
        'format' => '',
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current,
        'show_all' => false,
        'end_size' => $endsize,
        'mid_size' => $midsize,
        'type' => $type,
        'prev_text' => '&lt;&lt;',
        'next_text' => '&gt;&gt;'
    );

    if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
        $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );

    if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) )
        $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );

    return paginate_links( $pagination );
}
```

I use this function in my `search.php` template like this.

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php echo oenology_get_paginate_archive_page_links(); ?>
</div>
```

If I search in my search bar the url for the resulting page looks like this

`mysite.com/?s=term`

I'd like to have the german `suche` (means "search") instead …

`mysite.com/suche/term`

And the second bit … when clicking on the page 2 of the pagination the url looks currently like this …

`mysite.com/page/2/?s=term`

I'd like to have the german word the german word `seite` (for "page") instead. Maybe even like this …

`mysite.com/suche/term/seite/2`

Is that somehow possible with this function that @Chip provided? I can't seem to find a working solution for this.

Thank you in advance. I'd really appreciate some help.

---

**UPDATE**

```
function oenology_get_paginate_archive_page_links( $type = 'plain', $endsize = 1, $midsize = 1 ) {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;  
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

    // Sanitize input argument values
    if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'plain', 'list', 'array' ) ) ) $type = 'plain';
    $endsize = (int) $endsize;
    $midsize = (int) $midsize;

    // Setup argument array for paginate_links()
    $pagination = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current,
        'show_all' => false,
        'end_size' => $endsize,
        'mid_size' => $midsize,
        'type' => $type,
        'prev_next'    => false
    );

    if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
        $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'seite/%#%/', 'paged' );

    /*if ( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) )
            $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );*/

    return paginate_links( $pagination );
}

/**
 * Change search- & paginationbase
 */

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'wr_generate_rewrite_rules' );

function wr_generate_rewrite_rules( $rewrite ) {
    $rewrite->rules = array_merge( array(
         'suche/([^/]+)(?:/seite/(\d+))?/?' => 'index.php?s='.$rewrite->preg_index(1).'&paged='.$rewrite->preg_index(2)
    ), $rewrite->rules );
}

add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', 'wr_search_pagenum_link' );

function wr_search_pagenum_link( $link ) { 
    if ( !is_search() )
        return $link;

    // Attempt to parse the page number from the provided URL
    if ( !preg_match( '#/page/(\d+)#', $link, $matches ) )
        return $link;

    // Return a re-formed URL
    return home_url( '/suche/' . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) . '/seite/' . $matches[0] );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom naming of search permalink /search/](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63716/custom-naming-of-search-permalink-search)

Comment: @Hias: Bitte mach kane doppltn Fragn auf. Mia probiern des System so guat wia nua möglich am laufen z'hoidn und des is bei da derzeitign Flut eh schon fost unmöglich. Merci. (I lösch des wieder, wonnst z'ruck schreibst, wei ma do eigentlich ned Deitsch schreibm suitn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the primary reason that the GET parameter format is still used for searches is that search forms are regular GET forms that when submitted form URLs with the GET parameters appended.

But a further problem with using custom URLs to capture searches is that search terms can be arbitrary text, including slashes, etc, which can look ugly when baked into a URL.

Suppose we used your desired search URL format:

`mysite.com/suche/term`

And I searched for the term `"belegte brot"`, with the quotes. We end up with the URL:

`mysite.com/suche/%22belegte+brot%22`

Which isn't terribly pretty, and similar escaping needs to be done for any other special characters.

Nevertheless, it's still possible to achieve the permalink structure you are looking for.

**Step 1**: Register permalink structure

Hook on `generate_rewrite_rules` action, to add new patterns:

```
function my_generate_rewrite_rules( $rewrite ) {
    $rewrite->rules = array_merge( array(
        'suche/([^/]+)(?:/seite/(\d+))?/?' => 'index.php?s='.$rewrite->preg_index(1).'&paged='.$rewrite->preg_index(2)
    ), $rewrite->rules );
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_generate_rewrite_rules' );
```

This registers a rule at the very top of the rewrite rule stack, which will capture URLs of the forms `suche/<term>`, `suche/<term>/`, `seite/<term>/seite/<page>` and `seite/<term>/seite/<page>/` and transform them into the query variables `s=<term>` and `paged=<page>`

**Step 1a**: Regenerate permalinks by visiting the `Settings > Permalinks` page in the WP admin area.

**Step 2**: Insert JavaScript in your search form that will, instead of submitting a form using GET parameters, will instead redirect to a URL of the form above:

```
<form id="search" action="<?php echo home_url( '/suche/' ); ?>">
    <input name="s" />
</form>
<script>
    jQuery('#search').submit(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        location.href = jQuery(this).attr('action') + escape( jQuery('#search').find('[name="s"]').val() );
    });
</script>
```

This example shows a form whose `submit` event is captured and cancelled, instead updating the URL. **NB:** This is untested.

**Step 3**: Add a hook on the `get_pagenum_link` filter to form the expected URLs:

```
function my_search_pagenum_link( $link ) { 
    if( !is_search() )
        return $link;    // Do nothing unless on a search

    // Attempt to parse the page number from the provided URL
    if( !preg_match( '#/page/(\d+)#', $link, $matches ) )
        return $link;

    // Return a re-formed URL
    return home_url( '/suche/' . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) . '/seite/' . $matches[0] );
}
add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', 'my_search_pagenum_link' );
```

This should be sufficient to achieve your desired behavior.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the explanation. It almost works, however there one last little thing and I can't find the reason for this to happen. when on my `search` and the url lookls exactly like I want it to be `mysite.com/suche/term` … if clicking on page 2 the url updated to `mysite.com/suche/term/seite/2` and everything works fine - the page shows the results for the second page. But when clicking on page `1` again in the pagination the urls get kind of stacked on top of each other `mysite.com/suche/term/seite/2/seite/1` I updated my question with the exact code I'm working with right now. Ideas?

Comment: It's possible that either the `rewrite_canonical` filter or another `get_pagenum_link` filter is running. Put debugging notices on those hooks to see if they are getting hit and causing this  behavior. I am not familiar enough with the `paginate_links()` function to tell you why exactly this is hapening.

Comment: Oh, I see, I would try removing the lines that re-set `$pagination['base']` in your code. It looks like could be adding the additional `seite/1/` component.

Comment: it's not the `if statement` with `$pagination['base']`. If I comment-out this line too the urls change back to `suche/term?paged=2` - so this if statement is needed I guess. However it's funny that I'm able to change two params inside the `$args` for the `paginate_links()` to `seite` without chaning anything: `$pagination = array('base' => @add_query_arg('seite','%#%'),'format' => 'seite=%#%',…` I changed those two lines but the same effect. the `seite/2/seite/1/seite/2` thing still happens.

Comment: WordPress 3.4.2 was just released which may fix this issue.

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything unfortunately! If I comment-out the first if-statement in the `oenology_get_paginate_archive_page_links` too my permalinks for the pagination look like this … `/suche/lorem?paged=1` So the "/suche/" part works fine with your provided code, just the "/seite/1" for the pagination doesn't work.

Comment: The problem might be that the function you provided `my_search_pagenum_link()` doesn't seem to have any effect. If I comment-out `add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', 'my_search_pagenum_link' );` nothing changes at all and vice versa.

Comment: I would really appreciate some last thoughts on that! I can't seem to find any solution why the `my_search_pagenum_link()` function doesn't do anything.